# colorize D3 chord paths based on data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chord-diagram

I migrated this https://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/d2720fdaab1123df73f4806360a09c9e D3 Chord layout to D3v7. My current problem is, I want to utilize the *color* attribute from *var objects* to fill the individual paths. Those are currently grey.

I managed to get it done for the outer circle with

```
.style("fill", function (d) {
      return objects[d.index].color
])
```

I thought I could use the same line of code to display the respected color for the paths but I receive the error that objects[d.index].color is undefined, which confuse me. I assume I did not understood the path procedure fully, which makes me believe I do everything correct.. pathetic.

I appreciate any help.

```js
 // Setup

        var objects = [
            { id: 0, name: "Black Widow", color: "#301E1E" },
            { id: 1, name: "Captian America", color: "#083E77" },
            { id: 2, name: "Hawkeye", color: "#342350" },
            { id: 3, name: "The Hulk", color: "##567235" },
            { id: 4, name: "Iron Man", color: "#8B161C" },
            { id: 5, name: "Thor", color: "#DF7C00" }
        ]

        var flows = [
            { from: 0, to: 0, quantity: 0 },
            { from: 0, to: 1, quantity: 4 },
            { from: 0, to: 2, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 0, to: 3, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 0, to: 4, quantity: 5 },
            { from: 0, to: 5, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 1, to: 0, quantity: 4 },
            { from: 1, to: 1, quantity: 0 },
            { from: 1, to: 2, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 1, to: 3, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 1, to: 4, quantity: 4 },
            { from: 1, to: 5, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 2, to: 0, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 2, to: 1, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 2, to: 2, quantity: 0 },
            { from: 2, to: 3, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 2, to: 4, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 2, to: 5, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 3, to: 0, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 3, to: 1, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 3, to: 2, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 3, to: 3, quantity: 0 },
            { from: 3, to: 4, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 3, to: 5, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 4, to: 0, quantity: 5 },
            { from: 4, to: 1, quantity: 4 },
            { from: 4, to: 2, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 4, to: 3, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 4, to: 4, quantity: 0 },
            { from: 4, to: 5, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 5, to: 0, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 5, to: 1, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 5, to: 2, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 5, to: 3, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 5, to: 4, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 5, to: 5, quantity: 0 },
        ]

        var matrix = [];
        
        // Map flows data to valid matrix
        flows.forEach(function (flow) {
            //initialize sub-array if not yet exists
            if (!matrix[flow.to]) {
                matrix[flow.to] = [];
            }
            
            matrix[flow.to][flow.from] = flow.quantity;
        })   

        const width = window.innerWidth
        const height = window.innerHeight

        const svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")")

        // Übergibt die Daten-Matrix zu d3.chord()
        const root = d3.chord()
            .padAngle(0.05)
            .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)(matrix)

        // Fügt die Gruppen für den inneren Kreis hinzu
        svg
            .datum(root)
            .append("g")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(d => d.groups)
            .join("g")
            .append("path")
                .style("fill", "grey")
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .attr("d", d3.arc()
                    .innerRadius(width/2 - 210)
                    .outerRadius(width/2 - 200)
                )
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return objects[d.index].color
            })
            

        // Fügt Verlinkungen zwischen den Gruppen hinzu
        svg
            .datum(root)
            .append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(d => d)
            .join("path")
                .attr("d", d3.ribbon()
                    .radius(width/2 - 220)
                )
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return objects[d.index].color
                })
                //.style("fill", "grey")
                .style("stroke", "black")
```

```css
    body {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        fill: #2B2B2B;
        cursor: default;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    @media (min-width: 600px) {
        #chart {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Step 1 - Collaborations between MCU Avengers</title>

    <!-- D3.js -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
    
</head>



<body>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR:

Lines **92 through 94**:

```
.style("fill", function (d) {
    return objects[d.index].color
})
```

... become:

```
.style('fill', ({ index }) => objects.find(({ id }) => id === index).color)
```

And lines **107 through 109**:

```
.style("fill", function (d) {
    return objects[d.index].color
})
```

... become:

```
.style('fill', ({ source: { index } }) => objects.find(({ id }) => id === index).color)
```

### Explanation

You have two problems:

1. Your items `d` in the second method actually contain both "source" and "target", for instance:

```json
{
  "source": {
    "index": 0,
    "startAngle": 0.3399537106352038,
    "endAngle": 0.6119166791433668,
    "value": 4
  },
   "target": {
   "index": 1,
   "startAngle": 1.1378518740326522,
   "endAngle": 1.4098148425408152,
   "value": 4
  }
}
```

... and you therefore need to dig into either "source" or "target" before having access to an "index" attribute.

2. your `objects` Array contains references to items that are apparently ordered such that their "id" attribute corresponds to their index in the `objects` Array, but I presume it to be either an unreliable coincidence or an inadvertent oversight.

In any case, you seem to be disregarding the `index` property entirely, while I believe you meant to use it to identify each item. I suggest you use [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) here!

### Updated Code Snippet

```js
// Setup

        var objects = [
            { id: 0, name: "Black Widow", color: "#301E1E" },
            { id: 1, name: "Captian America", color: "#083E77" },
            { id: 2, name: "Hawkeye", color: "#342350" },
            { id: 3, name: "The Hulk", color: "##567235" },
            { id: 4, name: "Iron Man", color: "#8B161C" },
            { id: 5, name: "Thor", color: "#DF7C00" }
        ]

        var flows = [
            { from: 0, to: 0, quantity: 0 },
            { from: 0, to: 1, quantity: 4 },
            { from: 0, to: 2, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 0, to: 3, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 0, to: 4, quantity: 5 },
            { from: 0, to: 5, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 1, to: 0, quantity: 4 },
            { from: 1, to: 1, quantity: 0 },
            { from: 1, to: 2, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 1, to: 3, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 1, to: 4, quantity: 4 },
            { from: 1, to: 5, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 2, to: 0, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 2, to: 1, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 2, to: 2, quantity: 0 },
            { from: 2, to: 3, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 2, to: 4, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 2, to: 5, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 3, to: 0, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 3, to: 1, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 3, to: 2, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 3, to: 3, quantity: 0 },
            { from: 3, to: 4, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 3, to: 5, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 4, to: 0, quantity: 5 },
            { from: 4, to: 1, quantity: 4 },
            { from: 4, to: 2, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 4, to: 3, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 4, to: 4, quantity: 0 },
            { from: 4, to: 5, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 5, to: 0, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 5, to: 1, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 5, to: 2, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 5, to: 3, quantity: 3 },
            { from: 5, to: 4, quantity: 2 },
            { from: 5, to: 5, quantity: 0 },
        ]

        var matrix = [];
        
        // Map flows data to valid matrix
        flows.forEach(function (flow) {
            //initialize sub-array if not yet exists
            if (!matrix[flow.to]) {
                matrix[flow.to] = [];
            }
            
            matrix[flow.to][flow.from] = flow.quantity;
        })   

        const width = window.innerWidth
        const height = window.innerHeight

        const svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")")
                
        // Übergibt die Daten-Matrix zu d3.chord()
        const root = d3.chord()
            .padAngle(0.05)
            .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)(matrix)
            
        // Fügt die Gruppen für den inneren Kreis hinzu
        svg
            .datum(root)
            .append("g")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(d => d.groups)
            .join("g")
            .append("path")
                .style("fill", "grey")
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .attr("d", d3.arc()
                    .innerRadius(width/2 - 210)
                    .outerRadius(width/2 - 200)
                )
            .style("fill", function ({ index }) {
                return objects.find(({ id }) => id === index).color;
            })
            

        // Fügt Verlinkungen zwischen den Gruppen hinzu
        svg
            .datum(root)
            .append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(d => d)
            .join("path")
                .attr("d", d3.ribbon()
                    .radius(width/2 - 220)
                )
                .style("fill", function ({ source: { index } }) {
                    return objects.find(({ id }) => id === index).color;
                })
                //.style("fill", "grey")
                .style("stroke", "black")
```

```css
body {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        fill: #2B2B2B;
        cursor: default;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    @media (min-width: 600px) {
        #chart {
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Step 1 - Collaborations between MCU Avengers</title>

    <!-- D3.js -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
    
</head>



<body>
    
</body>

</html>
```